# From uint8_t to hex string array?

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, hex

I know it's a simple question, but I am completely lost.
I have in input a string:

```
input: 220209
```

I want:

```
output: uint8_t myarr[8]={0x22,0x02,0x09,0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00}
```

So myarr has always a dimension of 8, and if I have a lower input string I have to complete with 0x00. Can someone give me any idea?
Sorry for bothering you, any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You have the title backwards, according to your example you want to convert a hex string into a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strtol()` to convert 2 characters at a time, explicitly using base 16 makes it easy:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Assume s has an even number of hexdigit chars (at most 16) followed by a nul
void convert(const char *s, uint8_t out[static 8]) {
  int i = 0;
  // Handle 2 chars at a time
  while (*s) {
    char byte[3] = { *s, *(s + 1), 0 };
    out[i++] = strtol(byte, NULL, 16);
    s += 2;
  }
  // Fill the rest of the array with nuls
  for (; i < 8; i += 1) {
    out[i] = 0;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  const char *input = "220209";
  uint8_t myarr[8];

  convert(input, myarr);

  // Pretty-print the array using hex values
  fputs("uint8_t myarr[8] = { ", stdout);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {
    printf("0x%02" PRIx8, myarr[i]);
    if (i < 7) {
      fputs(", ", stdout);
    }
  }
  puts(" };");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (*s) ( ... s += 2; }` has a 50% chance of skipping right over the `'\0'` string terminator.

Comment: Providing input that doesn't match the expected format would cause problems, sure. If that's a situation OP might encounter, making it more robust will be good practice for them.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `sscanf()` to parse two characters at a time:

```
void convert(const char *s, uint8_t out[8]) 
{
    memset(out, 0, 8);
    while (sscanf(s, "%2"SCNx8, out++) == 1) {
        s += 2;
    }
}
```

The first line sets the 8 bytes to 0 by taking advantage of 64 bits arithmetics. Then we scan two characters from string s, reading an integer of type uint8_t from hexdecimal ASCII representation. If the read was successful, we move to the next two characters.

It looks like a [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) submission, but it's nice, because nothing gets copied.

Another version could be:

```
void convert(const char *s, uint8_t out[8])
{
    static char tbl[] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,10,11,12,13,14,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,10,11,12,13,14,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    };
    
    memset(out, 0, 8);
    while (*s) {
        *out++ = tbl[s[0]] * 16 + tbl[s[1]];
        s += 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `*(uint64_t*)out = 0;` is a strict aliasing violation and can also be UB if not properly aligned.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for pointing it out. Can you provide me a link to a good reference for learning more on that? I confess that "strict aliasing" is something I'm not really familiar with.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Fixed the strict aliasing violation with a `memset()`.

Answer (score -1):

Hope it can work for you

```
memset(myarr, 0, 8);
int szLen = strlen(szInput);
for(int i = 0; i < szLen / 2; i++) {
   uint8_t high = toupper(szInput[i*2]);
   uint8_t low = toupper(szInput[i*2 + 1]);

   if(high >= '0' && high <= '9')
       high = high - '0';
   if(low >= '0' && low <= '9')
       low = low - '0';
   if(high >= 'A' && high <= 'F')
       high = high - 'A' + 10;
   if(low >= 'A' && low <= 'F')
       low = low - 'A' + 10;
   myarr[i] = (high << 4) | low; // bit operation is faster than arithmetic
}
```

Comment: (a) Code without explanation is not a good answer. (b) `<< 8 +` is wrong because `+` has higher precedence than `<<`. (c) `<< 8` is the wrong shift amount.

Comment: What sould I use for <<8?

Comment: (d) This does not support hexadecimal digits above 9.

Comment: @kevin94 You should use `*16`, which corresponds to `<< 4`.